# GitAction: Trigger workflow on PR approval AND when base branch is main AND .csv file is updated

Tags: github, github-actions

I was trying with following code but it is not taking care of all 3 conditions due to following reason:

1. base_ref will only work on pull_request/push event not on pull_request_review
2. action `dorny/paths-filter@v2.2.1` only works with pull_request/push event

```
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  myJob:
    name: myJob
    if: github.event.review.state == 'approved' && startsWith(github.base_ref, 'main/')
    runs-on: [self-hosted, prd]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.2.0
      - name: Check if *.csv is modified
        uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2.2.1
        id: changes
        with:
          filters: |
            csv:
              - 'data/*.csv'    
      - name: Run process bmv script
        if: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.csv == 'true' }}
        run: |
          echo "-Started running script-"
```

Can any one suggest how can i handle all 3 conditions : PR approval, base branch as main and only csv is modified.

Comment: did you already try with `startsWith(github.event.pull_request.base.ref, 'main/')` ?

Comment: Actually, according to the review event context (cf [github.event.review payload here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#webhook-payload-example-35)), I understand you should use `startsWith(github.event.review.pull_request.base.ref, 'main')`. (almost what Matteo returned above)

Comment: I have tried ```startsWith(github.base_ref, 'main/')``` , let me try the above one. thanks @Matteo @GuiFalourd

Comment: Thanks Matteo, ```startsWith(github.event.pull_request.base.ref, 'main/')``` this worked... review.pull_request doesn't have property base.

Comment: Any idea how can I check for the 3rd condition from the original question that is to even check on particular file only changed like csv in my case. ```path``` works with pull request and push not with review... So i tried the ```dorny/paths-filter@v2.2.1``` but this also seems like works only with push/pull_request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer by doing Matteo's way and also tweaking existing code.
Tweaks: Updated `dorny/paths-filter@v2.2.1` to `dorny/paths-filter@v2.10.2` as this version support it to work on other than pull/pill_request events.

```
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]

jobs:
  myJob:
    name: myJob
    if: startsWith(github.event.pull_request.base.ref, 'main') && (github.event.review.state == 'approved')
    runs-on: [self-hosted, prd]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.2.0
      - name: Check if *.csv is modified
        uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2.10.2
        id: changes
        with:
          filters: |
            csv:
              - 'data/*.csv'    
      - name: Run process bmv script
        if: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.csv == 'true' }}
        run: |
          echo "-Started running script-"
```

Thanks for all the help, above is the complete working solution which check for all 3 conditions i.e run workflow only when PR is approved and PR has base branch as main and only csv file inside data folder is modified.